# Can someone clarify lifecycle and difference of Filter and Interceptor in Apache CXF?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

For example, suppose I have this filter

```
@WebFilter("/api/*")
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response); 
    }
}
```

and an interceptor

```
@Interceptor
public class HeaderLoggerInterceptor {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object validateHeaders(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        // pre-action
        Object result = ctx.proceed();
        // post-action
        return result; 
    }
}
```

1. which object will be invoked first when a service endpoint is hit?
2. if I want to call setAttribute to request so some additional values can be written to local_access log. It doesn't work in Interceptor, only seems to work with Filter.
3. is it a bad idea to have both in the service?
4. which one is better to validate header?
5. which one is better to write response log before sending back to the client?

I really can't find document on this topic. thanks

---

I will answer my own question after my experiment

[image: CXF Lifecycle of Filter and Interceptor]

However, I discover another strange problem.

- I am using an ExceptionMapper, which allows me to centralize the exception handling in one place;
- When there is a missing header, I throw out a custom MissingHeaderException;
- The exception will be caught by the Mapper, and we format it and provide a nice XML response back to the client

This logic works only with Interceptor not Filter. Any exception thrown from a Filter is not handled by the Mapper.